# How to change the strip color on kableExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

The color of the strips are very lite on `Kable` on Pdf output. So is there a way to change the color on `kable_styling(latex_options = "striped")`?

Comment: You may want to start a new issue on github for any future feature request :) https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of the `kableExtra`package @hao was kind to add this option. The answer can be found on [change the strip color on kableExtra](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/41)

Answer (score 1):

Cobbling together the link provided by @S.Perera above (where @hao states no functionality for hex codes yet), deciding I didn't like the available LaTeX color codes found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#Predefined_colors) (code for modifying just below that), an attempt to change stripe color described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397184/kable-styling-for-alternative-row-colors-in-rmarkdown), and my own desire to fine-tune with hex codes, I came up with the following:

In the YAML:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes: \definecolor{ltgray}{HTML}{D3D3D3}
---
```

`ltgray` is the new name for the color, `HTML` is the model (you can also do RGB or CMYK), and `D3D3D3` is the hex code for the color I want. Assuming my dataframe for the table is called `df`:

```
kable(df, format = "latex", booktabs=TRUE) %>%
    kable_styling(latex_options = "striped", stripe_color="ltgray")
```